# ASP.NET Conditional Markup Rendering According to Web.config Key

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, markup

I have a key in web.config as -

```
<add key="IsDemo" value ="true"/>
```

I want to show/hide markup based on above web.config entry for a **non-server html tag** without using code behind file (as there is no .cs file and there are no runat=server controls).
Something similar to following pseudo code:

```
IF ( IsDemo == "true" )
THEN
<tr>
    <td id="tdDemoSection" colspan="2" align="left" valign="top">
        <.....>
    </td>
</tr>
ENDIF
```

Does anyone know that we can write such conditional logic in .aspx markup? 
Please help!!!

**EDIT:**

Section I'm hiding or showing have some data like username and password. So, I do not want user to use Firebug or Web Developer Tools to see hidden markup. markup should not go to client side.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The syntax for something like that would be

```
<% if(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsDemo"] == "true") %>
<% { %>
<!-- Protected HTML goes here -->
<% } %>
```

This assumes that the page is in C#.

You can firm this code up by being more defensive around the AppSettings retrieval e.g. what happens in the case where the value is null etc.

Comment: Thanks. Made few changes to your code and added snippet below which worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

**Solution:-**

```
<% If (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("IsDemo").ToLower().Equals("true")) Then%>
    <tr>
       <.....>
    </tr>
<% Else%>
    <tr>
        <.....>
    </tr>
<% End If%>
```

Comment: Question is tagged with C#, this looks like VB.NET.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it right, you don't want to use server-side (aspx components, with runat="server" attribute) and just want to control display of html on aspx page then try this solution.

Create a property in codebehind file (or better still in some other config helper class):

```
//IN C# (OR VB) file
protected string Demo{
    get{ 
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsDemo"]=="true"?
                   "none":"block";
      }
}
```

In aspx page:

```
<tr style="display:<%= Demo%>;">
    <td>blah blah</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Section I'm hiding or showing have some data like username and password. So, I do not want user to use Firebug or Web Developer Tools to see hidden markup. markup should not go to client side.

Comment: Why the hell you are putting user-names and password on page?

Comment: Yeah. Your question is valid. :) I had asked same question to my client. But actually, it is not a password, but it is an Access code which is shared among several users.

Comment: then there is no simple way other than using server side control so that the stuff is never rendered in the first place.