# ASP.NET : Conditional Logic for 2 diff values in <TD> in ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, conditional-statements, itemtemplate

**Goal**: I have two different columns in a database. Depending on which client it is, I will either want to display the value from one column, or the other in this single  (which is inside an ItemTemplate associated to a LayoutTemplate).

**Research**: I tried looking up similar articles on SO, but they were for slightly different problems, including this one: [ASP.Net: Conditional Logic in a ListView's ItemTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083829/asp-net-conditional-logic-in-a-listviews-itemtemplate/1083855)

**Error**: I tried using an if statement in the aspx but it tells me I am missing ; even though I have it:

**default.aspx**:

```
 <td><%# if(isAAA()) { Item.} else { Item.}; %></td>
```

I also  tried:

```
  <td><%# if(isAAA()) { Item.; } else { Item.; } %></td>
```

I also tried:

```
   <td><% if(isAAA()) { Item.; } else { Item.; } %></td>
```

I also tried:

```
       <td><% if(isAAA()) { #Item.; } else { #Item.; } %></td>
```

I also tried the following, but it placed the value under the wrong column, and it displayed part of the aspx logic on the page:

```
if(isAAA() { <td><%# Item.%></td> else { <td><%# Item.%></td> }
```

*Note*: isAAA() is a method in the .cs file that checks a value in the Settings file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the following setup:

```
<% if (is()) %> 
            <% {  %>   
                 <td><%# Item. %></td> 
            <% } %>

            <% else %>
            <% { %>
                  <td><%# Item. %></td>
            <% } %>
```

This was the closest SO I found : [ASP.NET Conditional Markup Rendering According to Web.config Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734787/asp-net-conditional-markup-rendering-according-to-web-config-key)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<td><%= this.isAAA() ? Item.AAA_Group_ID.ToString() : Item.Group_ID.ToString() %></td>
```

Comment: Thanks. It's now saying "The name item does not exist in the current context' . It doesn't say that for any of the other columns where I use Item